# How to fix pac file not recognized for python selenium test?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, proxy, pac

For reasons I am not able to explain here in a short manner, I want to use a `pac` file for a `firefox` test (`python-selenium`) to coordinate the used proxy for various types of requests.

Here is the `pac` file I am using:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) 
{ 
    console.log("test proxy");
    lsjkd fhafh fasdfhsdjkl fhs
    if (url.substring(0, 3) === "ws:" || url.substring(0, 4) === "wss:") 
    { 
        return "DIRECT"; 
    } else { 
        return "PROXY 0.0.0.0:8080"; 
    }   
}
```

and here is the complete script for the test:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

selenium_proxy = webdriver.Proxy()
selenium_proxy.proxy_type = webdriver.common.proxy.ProxyType.PAC
selenium_proxy.proxyAutoconfigUrl = "/path/to/proxy.pac"

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_proxy(selenium_proxy)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

Because the `pac` file contains an obvious syntax error I expect the test to fail (like `UnknownError`). However, the page loads without problems and the test succeeds.

Why is the `pac` file not use inside the firefox driver? Or is it loaded but ignored? Is it possible to log some text from inside the `pac` file?

I tried to do that like above but (even without the syntax error) I cannot see the `console.log` anywhere (neither in the browser itself, for which I added the sleep of 10 seconds, so I can press F12 to check the browser's console).

How to be able to use the `pac` file for firefox?

**Addendum:**

You can even use the following `pac` file to see it is not being used at all:

```
//
// Define the network paths (direct, proxy and deny)
//

// Default connection
var direct = "DIRECT";

// Alternate Proxy Server
var proxy = "PROXY 0.0.0.0:8095";

// Default localhost for denied connections
var deny = "PROXY 0.0.0.0:65535";

//
// Proxy Logic
//

function FindProxyForURL(url, host) 
{           
    return deny;      
}
```

EACH request should be denied - but the test still works and the webpage is correctly requested...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the definition of the autoconfig URL!

One must not use a path like

```
selenium_proxy.proxyAutoconfigUrl = "/home/user/proxy.pac"
```

but a URL form

```
selenium_proxy.proxyAutoconfigUrl = "file:///home/user/proxy.pac"
```